# Can a limit approaching positive infinity be right sided?

Tags: calculus, limits, infinity

In other words is $\lim_{x \to \infty^{+}} f(x)$ ever meaningful/defined? Seems like it's intrinsically an implicit left sided limit to approach positive infinity. Also curious for the mirror case, left hand limit approaching negative infinity.

Comment: $\infty^+$ doesnt make any sense. Because $\infty$ isn't a number.

Comment: Limits to $-\infty$ and to $+\infty$ for functions whose domain is the extended real line $[-\infty,+\infty]$ are essentially the same idea as limits to $-1$ and to $+1$ for functions whose domain is the closed interval $[-1,+1].$ You can view these limits as one-sided limits, but one can also argue that the one-sided aspect is illusionary, since the approach to the limiting value is still an arbitrary approach relative to the space under consideration.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Why is the approach direction arbitrary? Isn't the whole point of sided limits that it's not arbitrary?

Comment: By arbitrary, I mean there is no restriction on the sequences used to approach the point, other than the sequences must belong to the space under consideration. I'm talking about using subspace topology notions, which is the standard way of taking care of all these semantical issues. Thus, in considering limits to $-1$ for functions whose domain is $[-1,+1],$ there is no conception of "left limit" because there is no left side of $-1.$ The "right limit" and "the limit" are the same for $-1.$

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Ah, I understand, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of convention is not used and is meaningless since $\infty$ is not a numbers but if we want to define accordingly to the others, forcing the definition, we should consider it as a “left side limit” as for $1^-$ on the interval $(0,1)$.

A definition for $(0, \infty)$ could be something like this

- $lim_{\infty^-}:= \lim_{a^-}$ as $a\to \infty$

But It doesn’t seem to be needed to define nor useful.